# ERROR 2019 Linker Error Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linker, unresolved-external

Hey I hope someone can tell me know to fix this issue I am having i keep getting an error 2019 from Visual studio for the following file. Now most of the functions have been removed so excuse the empty varriables etc.

Error   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl OpenOneDevice(void *,struct _SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA *,char *)" (?OpenOneDevice@@YAPAXPAXPAU_SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA@@PAD@Z) referenced in function _wmain  c:\Users\K\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test2\test2\test2.obj  test2

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>

SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInfoData;
HDEVINFO hwDeviceInfo;
HANDLE hOut;
char *devName;
//
HANDLE OpenOneDevice(IN HDEVINFO hwDeviceInfo,IN PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInfoData,IN char *devName);
//
HANDLE OpenOneDevice(IN HDEVINFO HardwareDeviceInfo,IN PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInfoData,IN char *devName) {
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA functionClassDeviceData = NULL;
    ULONG predictedLength = 0, requiredLength = 0;
    HANDLE hOut = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(HardwareDeviceInfo, DeviceInfoData, NULL, 0, &requiredLength, NULL);

    predictedLength = requiredLength;

    functionClassDeviceData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)malloc(predictedLength);
    if(NULL == functionClassDeviceData) {
        return hOut;
    }
    functionClassDeviceData->cbSize = sizeof (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

    if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(HardwareDeviceInfo, DeviceInfoData, functionClassDeviceData,
        predictedLength, &requiredLength, NULL)) {
        free( functionClassDeviceData );
        return hOut;
    }

    //strcpy(devName,functionClassDeviceData->DevicePath) ;

    hOut = CreateFile(functionClassDeviceData->DevicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    free(functionClassDeviceData);
    return hOut;
}


// 
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{



    hOut = OpenOneDevice (hwDeviceInfo, &deviceInfoData, devName);
    if(hOut != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        {
            // error report
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Been driving me mad for hours. Any help appreciated.

SOLVED THANKS TO CHRIS :-)

Add #pragma comment (lib, "Setupapi.lib")

Thanks

Comment: So where do you provide the function body?

Comment: @chris thanks for replying does a handle need a function body? I am porting the code from msdn forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/53ecfbad-54e4-418d-afb6-aafc4f731711

Comment: The handle is just the return value. I tried looking for that function, but couldn't find it, so I assumed it was handmade.

Comment: @chris Here is the full listing of it http://www-cdf.lbl.gov/~jmuelmen/ambush/pontifex/projects/surf/drivers/surface/surface.c thanks again

Comment: Search for `OpenOne` in the link. The function definition is the third and last result.

Comment: @chris cheers found that just now and added it as above however still the 2019 error. Is it the placement?

Comment: This one's for the setupdi... function, right? For that, here's what the documentation page says: *Library
Contained in Setupapi.lib. Link to Setupapi.lib.* That's done with a simple `-lSetupapi` in the command line build.

Comment: @chris lol yes you must be physic. Many thanks for all your help I will hunt down setupapi.lib and link to it. Been on that page 50 times today dont know how i missed it.

Comment: That was the actually the first thing I thought of when I saw there was a linker error until I saw what the linker was actually complaining about. It happens all too often. Plus I compiled the code to make sure :)